# Rails track the passing of the days

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a Rails app for a fantasy basketball game.
I need to implement a way to track the passing of the days.
I want to create a "fake" calendar, not related with the real calendar.
I was thinking to save the "current date" (in the game) in a model in DB, but it seems not the right choice, 'cause I will have that model with only 1 record, forever.
How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance,
Mauro

Comment: How does time flow in your fantasy world? Is one day here equal to one day there?

Comment: "not related with the real calendar" makes it seems like you are asking how to construct a whole new scheme to keep track of time, which may be a bit too arbitrary for an answer on here.

Comment: Is the fantasy time continuous, like 1000 s is one day, or just a succession of events?

Comment: The day in fantasy world is not related to real day. For example today is 23 August 2018, but in fantasy world may be 10 May 2020

Comment: If you don't want that _only 1 record_ to be modified in runtime, you can keep it a constant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your app will look, but, in trying to imagine such a thing it seems unlikely to me that you'll want only a single date saved in a database table. Are various events going to occur on various dates? Will those events need to have their dates recorded? If so, you may consider a database table of dates that will include all the dates in which relevant events occur, and which will have db relationships to the other tables that record those events. Then you can create a flag that marks a particular date as current. Or, perhaps, designate the most recent date in the table as current.

Comment: Yes, there are events that can occur at specific dates.

I think about the schedule: I have a Schedule model with these attributes: date, home team, away team, result, etc

I want to track the current day in this fantasy world, to say: today is 10 May 2020.

For now I'm thinking to proceed in this way: I create a Season model, with an attribute **today**, which I update every time all events for that day are completed. Obviously this model can have other attributes, and one time the season is over, I can create a new record.